# Remove highlight from current tab when button is clicked again, I am using setTabHighlighted() to highlight current tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-button, workspaceapi

I have created aura component to highlight tab onclick of button and it is working as expected. But I want to remove that highlight from tab when button is clicked again, not sure how to do this.

Please suggest.

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
<lightning:button label="Highlight Green" onclick="{! c.setFocusedTabHighlightGreen }" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
 ({
    setFocusedTabHighlightGreen : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.setTabHighlighted({
                tabId: focusedTabId,
                highlighted: true,
                options: {
                    pulse: true,
                    state: "success"
         }
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there could be other ways to do this but this work for me

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
    <aura:attribute name="highlightted" type="boolean" default="false" />

<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
<lightning:button label="Highlight Green" onclick="{! c.setFocusedTabHighlightGreen }" />
</aura:component>
```

you can then use highlightted attribute to check whether the tab is highlighted or not and remove highlight on that basis.

js

```
({
    setFocusedTabHighlightGreen : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            var highlighted=component.get("v.highlightted");



                workspaceAPI.setTabHighlighted({
                tabId: focusedTabId,
                highlighted: !highlighted,
                options: {
                    pulse: !highlighted,
                    state: "success"
         }
            });
             component.set("v.highlightted",!highlighted);   


        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: it worked.. thank you